# How do you show a dialog when a project is created in Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2005

I'm trying to create a web application project template for everyone to use here at work that will minimize the amount of work that we have to do to create a new application with all our normal stuff, and I was thinking that it would be nice to do some setup stuff (add some records to a database) when the developer creates a new application (only if they tell it to), and I would like to do it through a dialog like the one that pops up for unit testing when you create a new ASP.Net MVC project. Is there any way to write a custom dialog that will pop up when you create a new project from the our custom project template? I'm assuming they're just using some public interface for the MVC unit testing dialog, right?

We're still on Visual Studio 2005, though, so maybe something like that isn't supported until 2008?

Comment: Yeah, we're hoping we'll get to upgrade to 2010 when (within a year) it comes out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're going to need a little VSX for this ([Visual Studio Extensibility](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsx/default.aspx)). Install the [Visual Studio SDK](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyId=59EC6EC3-4273-48A3-BA25-DC925A45584D&displaylang=en) and look for samples about the [IWizard interface](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.templatewizard.iwizard.aspx).

That may be all you need. However, if you need a more extensive and powerful experience around custom creation of projects and project items, and easy addition of context-sensitive commands to Visual Studio, then take a look at the [Guidance Automation Extensions and Guidance Automation Toolkit](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/practices/aa718948.aspx).